# model binding fails on POST

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, angular-http

I have an ASP.Net Core 2.0 project that I'm using as a web api. The client-side is done with Angular 4. When I post my form data from my angular service to my API, the model properties on the server-side are always null. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I've tried various combinations of using `application/json` and `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. I've also tried both `[FromBody]` and `[FromForm]` attributes and in both cases the properties on my model are null.

Am I doing something wrong on the angular side during my post?

[image]

I've verified that my json string being posted (shown in the screenshot) contains my expected form data. It arrives null on the server though.

This is my angular service

```
import { Injectable, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, URLSearchParams, Headers, RequestOptions, Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';

import { CryptoData } from './cryptodata.interface';
import { Result } from './result.model';

@Injectable()
export class EncryptService implements OnInit {
    private options: RequestOptions;

    constructor(private http: Http) {
        this.options = new RequestOptions({
                headers: new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' })
            })
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    encrypt(data: CryptoData): Promise<Result> {
        let json: any = JSON.stringify(data);

        return this.http
        .post('/api/encrypt', json, this.options)
        .toPromise()
        .then(response => response.json());
    }

    decrypt(data: CryptoData) {

    }
}
```

This is my controller:

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public class CryptoController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost("~/api/Encrypt")]
    public IActionResult Encrypt([FromForm] CryptoRequest request)
    {
        // Testing
        return base.Ok(new Result(data: request.Content));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**[FromBody]** and **Content-Type: application/json** works very well for me with the same request in asp net core. I sent data from plugin in firefox: `{ "key" : "1", "content" : "cont" }`

[image]

Comment: The assumption is that the angular stuff is wrong - I don't know.